# How to install specific version of libhwloc5

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 with an already installed libhwloc5 package of version 1.11.2. I want to install it with version 1.11.5 or above. I've tried to remove it and run

```
sudo apt-get update
```

then I run

```
sudo apt-get install libhwloc5
```

but it installs the same old version, how can I specify the version of installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could specify the version of your package like this:

```
sudo apt-get install libhwloc5=<version-number-here>
```

Example: `apt-get install virtualbox=5.0.18-dfsg-2build1`